# Using an indexeddb wrapper with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, indexeddb, dexie, localforage

I'm new to Vue.js and JS frameworks other than jQuery. I'm also new to indexeddb and their wrappers.

For my next project, I have to integrate both of these together. After a lot of research, I've decided to use Vue.js for my framework. Looking at indexeddb wrappers, the one that I liked by far the most was jsstore, but I'm concerned that it won't be as easy to set up so that it syncs the UI with indexeddb as something like vue-idb (a Dexie/Vue crossover) or vue-localforage.

Can you easily integrate a generic indexeddb wrapper like jsstore with Vue.js? What does using one of these custom specialized solutions add to make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

JsStore can be easily integrated with vue or any framework. JsStore repository has examples for different framework. Here is the link - https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/JsStore/tree/master/examples

Here is link to vuejs example - https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/JsStore/tree/master/examples/vue-crud

On the other hand - when you are talking about IndexedDb, think like you need to call backend api. So call jsstore api and fetch items from database & then assign to different variables in different components.

Thus its upto you how & when you want to sync.